# Laravel 4 getting multiple collections

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model, eloquent

I am writing a function in my controller to return a json response. This is my function:

```
public function play($id){
        $quiz = Quiz::find($id);
        $questions = $quiz->question()->get();

        return Response::json(array(
            'quiz' => $quiz,
            'questions' => $questions));
    }
```

This works perfectly, however, I also have answers related to questions.
In my `Question` model I have this `answer()` function:

```
public function answer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Answer');
    }
```

And in my `Answer` model I have of course my `question()` function:

```
public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Question');
    }
```

How do I get my answers? I can't use;

```
$answers = $question->answer()->get;
```

And I can't use

```
//get the questions using query, but this returns nothing
$questions = Question::where('quiz_id', '=', $id);
$answers = $questions->answer()->get;
```

I hope I'm clear enough, I tried searching but I can't find anything, anybody please help :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [*eager loading*](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) to get a result where answers are **nested** inside questions:

```
$questions = $quiz->question()->with('answer')->get();
```

If you just want to get answers of *one single* question do this:

```
$question = Question::find(1);
$answers = $question->answer()->get();
```

Or simply use the **dynamic property**:

```
$answers = $question->answer;
```

---

Sidenote: I suggest you name `hasMany` relations in plural. `answers` instead of `answer`. This makes semantically more sense and tells you clearly if you get a collection or a single model as result.

Comment: Eager loading works. And about the sidenote; good thing to keep in mind, thanks.